# Replace filename every download

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

I want to replace the file name of my CSV file everytime I will download it. How can i do that? I use codeigniter here and jquery to download the HTML Table as CSV file.

For example I  have `myCSV.csv` in my downloads path and I want to download again the table with the same name `myCSV.csv` and replace the old one automatically.

My problem is everytime i will download the table the output will became this "myCSV.csv" and the second download is here `"myCSV(1).csv"`. What should I do for that?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot force the browser to replace the file when another file with the same name is downloaded.

Comment: yea this is browser behaviour, nothing you can do on your end.

Comment: how sad it is. I badly need it because i can't do the automatic update in CSV file.

Comment: For the sake of posterity it's worth noting this is a good thing! If you could force browsers to overwrite files on the local file system that would be a huge security hole.